# Which Maven archetype for webapp

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-archetype

I am pretty new to Maven and I have the following question when I shall:

Build a web application (Java EE 6) and use web-services. If I use one of the maven arcetypes I get a src/java/main & src/java/test and a web app folder. This is packaged as a WAR, but can I use webservice API when the package is WAR? How do you use Maven when you want to use all API's and create a web app?

Comment: Did you google? https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/using_jax_ws_with_maven

Comment: I want to know if I can uae the standard maven arcetype and still use the whole Java EE stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I'd I understand your question, but the archetype you use to create the project is of no importance. It is a simple way to create some of the artifacts that is needed.
If you want to use Webservices add the appropriate dependencies (most likely scoped as 'provided' since your container will already supply the implementation.

If you package it as a WAR you will not be able to use the full EE stack (only servlets) unless you're deploying to a EE6 compliant application server.
If you want to use EJBs and REsource Adapters you need to package it as an EAR (EJB supported in WAR as o EE6 as mentioned above).

I think there is an archetype for a "full" EE application as well if you want more modules and packaging :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, it seems like you understood what I meant:) What I am is to change from using the Eclipse projects to Maven. In Eclipse I have made one EJB project, one Dynamic Web Project and then added those to an EAR project. Now, in Maven if I use the basic Maven archetype (just to be as simple as possible) I get the standard directory layout. Is it correct that in a Maven project you mix the code (both use packages to structure of course) from both EJBs and Web app code such as backing beans? Do you then get Maven to make one EJB and one WAR artifact and then combine these two an EAR, is that correct

Comment: Good that I got it right :). Basically what you do is package your EjBs in one or more jar modules, packaging "ejb" and then one or more web modules, packaged as "war". Finally you have your "deployment" project or "application" packaged as a "ear". You specify dependencies between these modules and most likely combine it with a "maste/parent" project where you can specify versions for dependencies and so on. I would recommend reading up on Maven and multimodule projects.